# Mapping two properties one to many to the same collection

Tags: c#-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3 code first. How do I create two "one to many"-relationships between two properties in class A and a collection in class B?

My model:

```
public class Shaft
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Coupling FirstEnd { get; set; }
    public virtual Coupling SecondEnd { get; set; }
}

public class Coupling
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Shaft> Shafts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a one-to-many relationship is called **one**-to-many because there is **one** element on the first end of the relationship and many elements on the other end. You also can have a **zero or one**-to-many relationship which only means that the element on the not-many side can be `null` (or `NULL` in the database).

What you are trying to define is a **two**-to-many (or perhaps **zero or one or two**-to-many) relationship. Such a thing does not exist in a relational database nor does it exist in Entity Framework.

When you define a relationship with EF you always need **pairs** of two navigation properties in source and target class. It *is* possible to omit *one* of the navigation properties but that does not mean that you can move the end of this relationship to another navigation property that already belongs to another relationship.

In your specific case you have two relationships because your two navigation properties `FirstEnd` and `SecondEnd` in `Shaft` represent two different foreign keys. Therefore you either need two collections in `Coupling` or you can relate the existing property `Coupling.Shafts` to either `FirstEnd` or `SecondEnd` but not to both. The other reference would refer to an "invisible" not exposed navigation collection in `Coupling`. (This is what will happen with the mapping in your own answer: EF will take the second mapping block that overwrites the first one, create a relationship between `SecondEnd` and `Shafts` and then another relationship between `FirstEnd` and a not exposed relationship end in `Coupling`, *not* `Shafts` again.)

The solution with two collections - which makes more sense in my opinion - would look like this:

```
public class Coupling
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Shaft> ShaftsWithFirstEndHere { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shaft> ShaftsWithSecondEndHere { get; set; }
}
```

And this mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Coupling>()
    .HasMany(x => x.ShaftsWithFirstEndHere)
    .WithOptional(x => x.FirstEnd);

modelBuilder.Entity<Coupling>()
    .HasMany(x => x.ShaftsWithSecondEndHere)
    .WithOptional(x => x.SecondEnd);
```

You can create a readonly and not mapped helper property to concatenate the two collections togother to one collection, but this concatenation will happen in memory after the two navigation collections already have been loaded:

```
public class Coupling
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Shaft> ShaftsWithFirstEndHere { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shaft> ShaftsWithSecondEndHere { get; set; }

    // not mapped to DB because it has only a getter = readonly
    public IEnumerable<Shaft> Shafts
    {
        get { return ShaftsWithFirstEndHere.Concat(ShaftsWithSecondEndHere); }
    }
}
```

There is no kind of mapping which would do such a concatenation automatically. Be aware that a navigation collection property in a one-to-many relationship is just the result of a query by a foreign key in the dependent table (= `Shaft` in your example). The foreign key which is used to populate a collection (by using `Include` for example or when lazy loading is triggered) is well defined by the relationship mapping and it is only one key - either the key for `FirstEnd` or the key for `SecondEnd` but not both. What you are trying to achieve is the combined concatenated result of *two* queries by two different foreign keys. And that's not possible with relationship mapping.

Comment: I'm still fresh in the ef-world. Does it show? Thanks for clarifying this for me. My solution gave me the expected behaviour in the database but once I tried to use EF I got a big error. I'll delete it since I don't want it to accidentally lead other newbies astray.